# Fixing 'TypeError' in Poisson Regression (using Python)

Tags: python, statistics, regression, poisson, dummy-variable

I'm running a Poisson Regression in Python, and it's throwing the following error:

> TypeError: from_formula() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

How can I fix it? My code is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations import GEE
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import (Exchangeable,
    Independence,Autoregressive) 
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson

# 'df' is the dataframe containing all the data
f1 = "net_unique_bids ~ city1 + city2 + city3 + city4 + item_category1 + item_category2 + item_category3 + item_condition1 + item_condition2 + item_condition3 + asking_price + description_char_count + num_of_photos" 
model1 = GEE.from_formula(formula=f1, data=df, cov_struct=Independence(), family=Poisson())
```

**Background:** I'm modeling bids recieved (dependent variable) in my auctions website with features such as `city` (categorical), `item_category` (categorical), `asking_price` (continuous), `num_photos` (continuous) etc.

My overall aim is to find which features have the highest influence on bids received. This way, I can focus my energies on improving features that matter the most.

Comment: I guess, you haven't provided positional arguments to `from_formula` method. Pls share the `from_formula` code.

Comment: `def from_formula(cls, formula, groups, data, subset=None,
                     time=None, offset=None, exposure=None,
                     *args, **kwargs):`
You did not specify `groups`, hence it throws an error

Comment: @Uvar: what's the `groups` parameter expecting?

Comment: `groups : array-like or string
            Array of grouping labels.  If a string, this is the name
            of a variable in `data` that contains the grouping labels.`

Possibly the index of your dataframe? :/ otherwise, id of which city you are looking at; that would require taking city1...city4 out of the formula though.

Comment: @Uvar: Could you add all this as an answer? I'd accept it. I'm still hazy about groups, but I suppose I should pose that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, syntax for the model definition should follow:

```
def from_formula(cls, formula, groups, data, subset=None, 
                time=None, offset=None, exposure=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

You did not specify groups, hence it throws an error.

> > groups : array-like or string Array of grouping labels. If a string, this is the name of a variable in data that contains the grouping labels.

Possibly you could try for no grouping using the index of your dataframe? :/ Otherwise, using the id of which city you are looking at to separate the data into four groups to regress on; that would require taking city1...city4 out of the formula though. I am not particularly clear on what would suit your need here..

Comment: **1)** What's weird is that I have a couple of categorical variables - so technically, I'd be passing all of them into `groups`? **2)** In that case `f1` in my code would just contain continuous variables?

Comment: That does seem like the most `clean` way of doing it; as it probably is difficult to put numerical values on categories anyway..